# Is $T_{14}(f,0)(x)=T_{15}(f,0)(x)$ for polynomial degree $3$?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion

True or False (no explanation)?

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial of degree $3$, the following equation applies to the Taylor polynomials $T_{14}(f,0)$ and $T_{15}(f,0)$ of $f$ in $x_0=0$:

$T_{14}(f,0)(x) = T_{15}(f,0)(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Attempt: I would say its false, if i think about trigonometric polynomials?

Comment: Since you bring up *trigonometric polynomials,* without defining what *polynomial* means, this question is ambiguous. Usually, polynomial just means linear combinations of non-negative integer powers of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $f$ is a polynomial function of degree $n\ge 1$, then $f'$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ (*). It follows that, $f^{(k)}$ is the zero polynomial for every $k\ge n+1$.

On the other hand, the coefficients of the Taylor series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$ of a function $f$ at $0$ are $a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$.

Combining both facts, if $f$ is a polynomial function of degree $3$, then the $k^{th}$ coefficient of its Taylor polynomial at $0$ is $0$ for every $k\ge 4$. In particular, the sequence of its Taylor polynomials is stationary, that is constant from index $4$.

(*) This is true if the base field has characteristic $0$.